# Can I export Sass variables and import them into a Angular Typescript variables?

Tags: angular, typescript, sass

I have been looking at this for awhile.  I have my application right now as it is.  We have variables defined in the scss for coloring.  I am trying to import the variables into Typescript so I could submit them to servers.

I have a bunch of font and color strings in my Angular component, but i figured to push them into a scss file as it is used for design.  The issue is that I dont know how to fetch the colors.

I saw some people doing something similar in Javascript, but I have currently been unable to reproduce it in Typescript.

Ideally, I want do do:

Scss:

```
:export { myVariable:#ffffff; }
```

NGTypescript:

```
import {styles} from "./styles.scss";
```

and then do something akin to:

```
onPostRequest(){ let color = styles.myVariable; ... }
```

When i get to the import line above, it will state: *Cannot find module './icon-picker.component.scss'.ts(2307)*

I have seen in similar examples like React, which does similar, but i am having issues also porting that concept to Angular.  https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules/issues/86 shows concepts I was noticing.  Here is also a Javascript walkthrough which seems to also have issues with: https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/sxbrscjuqu-share-scss-variables-with-javascript

Comment: Have you tried using [style] or [ngClass] instead to create bindings of the styles to your `.ts` instead. ?

Comment: The issue i was having is not so much in the UI, but the inevitable state of needing to submit the color to a server.  So if i am using classes, how do i get the *color*'s value out of the class.  Right now I am using the style to do:  `[style]="{'color': myColorVar"` and have myColorVar in my TS, but i was thinking that colors and anything UI oriented should be abstracted to the scss file for ease of updating the uniformity of the app without weird little niche ui color discrepencies being overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to define the colors as variables in src/styles.scss, linking them up with CSS selectors and referencing these selectors in the component html file?

For example:

```
$primary-color: #333;
$secondary-color: #777;
.primary-color {
   color: $primary-color;
}
.secondary-color {
   color: $secondary-color;
}
```

And then in your html component:

```
<p class="primary-color">Text with primary color</p>
<p class="secondary-color">Text with secondary color</p>
```

For your interest you can also change the component css to scss by renaming the *.css and updating the StyleUrls reference in the component ts file.

Comment: The issue i am trying to get is submit colors to a server, so I am trying to figure out how to store the `$primary-color` in a js variable in order to submit it in a payload.